# Can't tombstone ItemsSource of a ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, tombstoning

I have a `ListBox` populated with data coming from XML.
Fine so far, the problem is that I get some errors when I try to tombstone it.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        State["listbox1"] = listBox1.ItemsSource;
    }
```

Then:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (State.ContainsKey("listbox1"))
        {
            listBox1.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)State["listbox1"];
        }
    }
```

When I hit the start button I already get an error. The `App.xaml.cs` opens and the line below becomes yellow

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

I've also used tombstoning helper but it did not return the items in my listbox.

Comment: What type of item? Is it serializable?

Comment: BRB, getting my magic exception 8 ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the listbox bound to? And what error are you seeing?

If it's a DataServiceCollection, you may have tracking turned on & you cannot put it flatly in Isolated Storage or State dictionaries. Should be fine if using ObservableCollection.

Thanks!

Comment: No error is shown, only that line turns yellow.
The listbox is bound to data coming from a xml:
    var tab = from c in xml.Descendants("tbody").Descendants("tr")
...
listBox1.ItemsSource = tab;

Comment: How about you try serializing "tab" on its own. Can you put that in State dictionary?

Comment: I tryed to, but I can not access it. Its is a local variable inside an openReadCompleted method...

Comment: Seems like I cant do anything like this: State["list"] = ienumerable type variable. ANy ideias would be nice

Comment: Yes I should be able to. Let's do this .. define an ObservableCollection<T> at class level .. where T could be generic like string or a custom class. Then fill up the collection on your Completed method & then try putting the collection in State.

Comment: I defined an ObservableCollection<IEnumerable> variable, but linq to xml returns me an ienumerable. So when I try to fill it, i get a invalid cast exception...

Comment: Ok wait .. ObservableCollection already implements the IEnumerable interface, so you are double-doing it. Let's make it simple .. so your LINQ returns an IEnumerable<string> or IEnumerable<CustomClass>, right? You should be able to tombstone the IEnumerable directly. Let's try that.

Comment: my LINQ returns an IEnumerable<CustomClass>, but When i try:
ObservableCollection variable = linq statement I get an cast error...

Comment: Simply put the IEnumerable<CustomClass> in State.

Comment: I´ve already tried that, but when I navigate to my app it does not fill the list...

Comment: Wel I Will try that too, but I found the answers using Isolated Storage instead of State. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329483/isolated-storage-security-exception-on-windows-phone/8336519#8336519 THX!